# TCP Server and Client

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i'm trying to write a TCP server and client so that when the client connects, a file is sent back from the server. Here's my code for the server:

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = '0.0.0.0'
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(10)

file_to_send = ('file_to_send.txt')

print '[*] Listening on %s:%d' % (bind_ip,bind_port)

def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print '[*] Received %s' % request
    client_socket.send('')
    client_socket.close(file_to_send)

while True:
    client,addr = server.accept()
    print '[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d' % (addr[0],addr[1])
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

And here is my code for the client:

```
import socket

target_host = '0.0.0.0'
target_port = 9999

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_port))
client.send('ACK!')

response = client.recv(4096)
print response
```

When the server and client are run, the server returns the error 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted' and when the client is run I get the error ' The requested address is not valid in its context'

Does anyone know why these errors are occurring or how I might be able to fix it.

Comment: Your client code is talking to `0.0.0.0` which isn't a valid address (in the server it just means "Listen to all incoming connections")

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of inaccurate example code. The server code you posted does not cause the issue you're describing (the client code does, but we'll get to that).

#### Server

The issue with the server code is that you're binding to the same `(address, port)` twice. Whether this is from wrong indentation or wrong logic it's tough to say, but that error message comes from binding the same protocol to the same address with the same port number more than once at the same time.

The rest of the code seems fine, though you can't do `client_socket.close("some string")` as you're doing here. `socket.close` does not accept any arguments.

#### Client

There's a simple solution here -- just change the `target_host` to something reasonable. You cannot connect to `0.0.0.0`. This should be the addressable IP of the server in the smallest scope possible. Presumably if this is a toy program this is something like `localhost`.

(N.B. you bind the server to `'0.0.0.0'` to tell it to accept connections going to any destination IP. You could bind the server instead to `'127.0.0.1'` to inform the server that it will ONLY be known as `localhost` and never anything else.)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before and it was that I was running old versions of the program on the same port, restarting the PC or closing the processes in task manager should fix it.

I'm aware that this was asked over a year ago, so OP has probably restarted their PC since then, but hopefully this will help someone looking for a solution for a similar problem.